# MacOS pf equivalent to iptables rule

Tags: macos, network, pfctl

I am looking to implement a rule like the following iptables rule on my Mac.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 10.244.1.8 -p tcp --dport 4369 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4369
```

Context: In my current setup I am port forwarding a container in k8s through `kubectl port-forward` and I am trying to, when I ping the IP of the running erlang node on the container be able to translate this IP into the localhost to carry the processing (the setup can be found on this post https://www.mendrugory.com/post/remote-elixir-node-kubernetes/)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've written pf rules, but I've never done iptables - what does the rule do specifically?  Does it forward traffic from 10.244.1.8 port 4369 to your localhost port 4369?

Comment: Yes it does that, by translating the output request into localhost.
At least is what I have understood from the article.
I am really new to iptables and pf

Comment: I'm trying to go from regular English to pf  :)  It's easier for me to figure out the rule that way if I know what you want to accomplish.   I don't know what all the flags are for or "DNAT" etc.  I'd have to learn some iptables first.

Answer (score 2):

After having struggle with this issue for a long time I was able to achieve the desired effect by:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias <ip>
rdr pass on lo0 inet proto tcp from any to <ip> port <port> -> 127.0.0.1
```